# Cordova + Ionic App run in background and resume to the last screen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing a new version of an app that is a kind of stopwatch that after some amount of time make a step or reach a checkpoint. This stopwatch should be run hours and hours and hours without stop.

When the app works in foreground there are no problems but when the app pass in background some strange happens and after a some amount of time seems that the app is killed, and when I come back to the app is restarted.

The old app made with cordova + sencha touch I don't had this behavior and could stay days running in background (without using plugins to do this).

I don't necessarily need that the app stay running in background because I only need to know when the stopwatch was started, I only would like to come back and resume the app to the last screen.

How can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things that could happen meanwhile the app is in background, so you could probably save the current app state on the app exit/pause event, save the clock time.

Once the user return, somehow read your last state, "recreate" the last state, check the current time and compute the time that has passed to update your stopwatch.

You could probably rely on a server time instead of the device time.

Comment: Yeah, using `localStorage`, you can persist those times.

Comment: @Peter/@manzapanza how was this achieved?  do you just update the localstorage value every second and compare it to the start time? Or do you only set the localstorage value on window.onbeforeunload or something similar?

Comment: In my case, that I only need to "recreate" the state of the stopwatch view, I save the state when the stopwatch starts and I delete the state when click on pause or stop and then, when the app launch, I check if a saved state exist and redirect to the stopwatch route re-setting the stopwatch timers. If you want to recreate always any views/routes you could save the state only when the state change, for example catching the event $stateChangeSuccess if you are using ui-router;